# Core Data and battery consuming

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, battery

I am creating an App with some informations stored in a tableView (populated with CoreData objects) in which you can tap on a cell to change its name from another ViewController.
To show the name in the TableView after coming back and also memorizing it in CoreData I came up with two options:

- Saving the change in CoreData, going back to the TableView and reloading all its data reading again all the CoreData
- Saving the change in CoreData, but going back sending the edit through Delegate and don't use CoreData

Which one is the best one talking about Battery consuming etc?

Thank you so much, Nico

Comment: I suspect that neither would have an appreciable effect on battery life.  You can use a fetched results controller to automatically update your tableview based on core data changes.

Comment: @Paulw11 How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/10/optimizing-core-data-performance-using-nsfetchedresultscontroller